# Retrieve first occurence in python for 2 data frames

Tags: python

I have a first data frame where

```
Name  | Age
Teddy | 20
John  | 30
```

I have a second data frame like below

```
Name  | Transport
Teddy | Airplane
Teddy | car
John  | motorocyel
```

I would like to do a merge on left on only the first occurence. i.e

```
Name  | Age | Transport
Teddy | 20  |  Airplane
John  | 30  |Morotorcyle
```

The best way I could think was to dedup the second dataframe and then merge. But is there any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think that is an appropriate way to do it. Personally, I would use `map` instead of merge:

Given the starting data:

```
>>> df1
    Name  Age
0  Teddy   20
1   John   30

>>> df2
    Name   Transport
0  Teddy    Airplane
1  Teddy         car
2   John  motorocyel
```

## Using `map`

```
# De-dupe and create map series
mymap=df2.drop_duplicates('Name').set_index('Name')['Transport']

# Map
df1['Transport'] = df1['Name'].map(mymap)
```

And the result:

```
>>> df1
    Name  Age   Transport
0  Teddy   20    Airplane
1   John   30  motorocyel
```

## Using `merge`

Or, using `merge`, as you were saying:

```
>>> df1.merge(df2.drop_duplicates('Name'))
    Name  Age   Transport
0  Teddy   20    Airplane
1   John   30  motorocyel
```

You can also drop the duplicates *after* you merge (if you want):

```
>>> df1.merge(df2).drop_duplicates('Name')
    Name  Age   Transport
0  Teddy   20    Airplane
2   John   30  motorocyel
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the first non-null line of a group, you can use

```
df2.groupby('Name').first()
```

Then you merge/join as usual.